# an ancestry VERSUS ancestries

Tags: meaning

**Random House Learner's Dictionary of American English © 2023**

*ancestry /ˈænsɛstri/  n., pl. -tries.*

1 the group of people from whom someone descended:
**had an ancestry of Puritan settlers.** [countable, usually singular]

2 line of descent; lineage:

**of Chinese ancestry.** [uncountable]

= = = = = =
My question:

**What's the difference between "an ancestry" and "ancestries"?**

An ancestry is a group of people. So, I can say "Everyone has an ancestry" and "Everyone has ancestries". The latter sounds weird. And I think the latter doesn't mean "Everyone has ancestors".

1 "Everyone has an ancestry"

2 "Everyone has ancestries"

3 "Everyone has ancestors"

Does 1 equal 2 in meaning?

Does 2 equal 3 in meaning?

Comment: We wouldn't normally pluralise ***ancestry*** when referring to the ancestral background of a single person, so your #2 sounds a bit weird to me. But of course, we each have 2 parents, whose separate ancestries are part of ours, so *in principle* it's a credible usage. Equally obviously, the *concept* of every person / living organism having an ***unbroken lineage of progenitors*** is subtly different to simply referring to those progenitors ***as individuals***, so you would choose between #1 and #3 depending on which aspect you wanted to focus on.

Comment: ...also see [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+an+ancestry+of%2Chad+their+ancestry+in&year_start=1850&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20), showing that we're more likely today to say *they **had their ancestry in** Puritan settlers* rather than that *they **had an ancestry of** Puritan settlers*.

Comment: Have you looked up "ancestor" in a dictionary? Why do you think it might mean the same as "ancestry"?

Comment: Where did I say that "ANCESTOR" might mean "ANCESTRY"? I said that "ancestors" might mean "ancestries".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ancestries* is an uncommon word.

*Ancestry* refers either to the relationship of being ancestors and descendents, in which case it is uncountable, or to the collection of ancestors of an individual or group.

So we would only talk about *ancestries* when we are referring to the descent of two or more different people or groups.

So your 1 and 3 are near enough the same in meaning, but 2 would be very odd: it would be saying that (for some reason) everybody had more than one descent or set of ancestors.

I can just about conceive of a person who was adopted talking about their "ancestries" - meaning their birth ancestry and their adopted ancestry (though it is not usual to talk about "adopted ancestry")' or *perhaps* somebody might talk about their father's ancestry and their mother's ancestry as their "ancestries" (especially if their parents came from different cultures). But both of these are very unusual ways of saying it.

**Edit**: the iWeb corpus has 20,832 instances of my/his/their ancestors", 3608 instances of "my/his/their ancestry", and only 23 of "my/his/their ancestries".